# SQL Group result with specific criteria

Tags: sql

I need to select and group only the ID's where all of their `ConditionId` values are `1`

```
   ID     ConditionId
    2       0
    2       1
    2       0
    3       0
    3       0
    4       1
    4       1
```

The result should be:

```
ID     ConditionId             
4       1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by checking if the row count per id equals the row count of conditionid = 1 per id, in the table.

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having count(*) = count(case when conditionid = 1 then 1 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only have 0s and 1s in the data, this should work:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(ConditionId) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, ConditionId 
FROM Table 
WHERE ConditionId=1 
  AND ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE NOT ConditionId = 1)
```

Comment: Please provide some information in addition to the code to help make this answer more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to do:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having max(ConditionId) = min(ConditionId) and max(ConditionId) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id
  from t
  group by id
  having sum(abs(1-ConditionId)) = 0;
```

or

```
select distinct id from t
minus
select distinct id from t where ConditionId <> 1;
```